# Getting 500 error on some docs but not others. Why?

Tags: ajax, post, office-js, word-addins

My add-in for MS Word works for some docs but not others. For test-doc-A, it works fine. I get the results I want. test-doc-B throws a 500 error on the $.ajax call that sends the text to the server. Both docs are one page. Granted, 500 errors are supposed to be "server" side. But what could be so different between these docs that's causing this?

The server logs don't indicate anything (to my eye) that tells me what the issue is.

```
test-doc-A (All Good)
2019-02-28 23:41:33 MyApiEndPoint POST /api/Document/Upload X-ARR-LOG-ID=8b253a46-bca8-4981-9ded-3fdf671fe63c 443 - myIpAddressMozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - https://localhost:44399/Home.html?_host_Info=Word$Win32$16.01$en-US myServerUrl 200 0 0 664 3793 46

test-doc-B (500 Error)
2019-02-28 23:42:13 MyApiEndPoint POST /api/Document/Upload X-ARR-LOG-ID=b0095aa0-9fc5-4a26-83b0-40d44ff160ba 443 - myIpAddress Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - https://localhost:44399/Home.html?_host_Info=Word$Win32$16.01$en-US myServerUrl 500 0 0 326 11306 46
```

Is there some way to compare the text that's being sent? Am I using the right method 'range.load("text")'?

The only difference between the docs appears to be formatting. But, I'm just sending the text, regardless of formatting, aren't I?

Do I need to "clean" the text before sending? Just so confused, right now.

```
function sendTextToServer() {
   Word.run(function (context) {
    var doc = context.document;
    var range = doc.body;

    range.load("text");

    return context.sync()

        .then(function () {
            var myData = '{\"FileName\": \"WordAddIn-Test\",\"Text\": \"' + range.text + '\" }';

            // begin promise
            var promise = $.ajax({
                url: urlToUse + "/Upload",
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate");
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                data: myData,
                success: function (data) {
                    log("sendTextToServer Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    log("sendTextToServer promise Error: " + errorMessage + "  : " + JSON.stringify(xhr) + "  : " + textStatus);
                }
            });
            // end promise

            // do something with promise
            promise.done(function (data) {
                myDocID = data.documentID;
                log("sendTextToServer myDocID: " + myDocID);
                log("url = " + urlToUse + "/Status?documentID=" + myDocID);
                setTimeout(function () { goDoSomethingElse(); }, 2000);
            });
        })
        .then(context.sync);
   }).catch(function (error) {
        log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            log("Something went wrong. Trying again");
        }
    });
}
```

"Looks like I picked the wrong week to quit sniffing glue."
   ~Steve McCroskey

Comment: Does the `error` callback to the ajax call run? What is the errorMessage?

Comment: Found the issue- straight double and single quotes in the text were breaking my JSON obj. I can replace them easily but can I perform a regex on the text so I can intelligently replace straight quotes with proper opening and closing quotes?

Comment: UPDATE: The quotes are not the only issue. What I've found is putting an un-escaped path reference, like "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\" in the text throws a 500 error.  Hyperlinks and urls don't. "c:" doesn't, but "c:\" does. It doesn't matter if the path line is in quotes or not. i.e. "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\" or c:\inetpub\wwwroot\. It doesn't even have to have "c:". I've tried it with "\bob\sam\" and it still throws 500 error.  However, escaping all the slashes seems to resolve it. i.e. "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\" Maybe the issue is it's interpreting the single \ as an escape character, itself.